# localhost resolve to old computer name

Tags: iis, localhost, computer-name

I have recently changed my computer name.

Now when I want to access web server (IIS) on my computer https://127.0.0.1 resolves to new computer name, but if I write https://localhost resolves to my old computer name.

Web page does not work with old computer name.
What can I do so localhost will resolve to my new computer name?

Comment: "if I write https://localhost resolves to my old computer name" is not a typical behavior caused by either the browser or IIS. What kind of web page is hosted there in this site? That page might cache the old computer name so you need to dig into it to resolve that.

Comment: Are there any rewrite rules? Because localhost is not resolved to comouter name on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

@Lex Li pointed me to right direction.
I am using Siemens WinCC Unified runtime.
I removed the project and added it again. Now it resolves to my new computer name.